# Is the total length of the inner sheet of a two ply roll of toilet paper shorter than the outer sheet?

Tags: geometry

If you look at any individual square of two plies, each ply looks the same. But musn't the inner ply be shorter?

Wouldn't the inner ply develop kinks if it was the same length as the outer ply? Or are they both thin enough, and the total length short enough, that the required length difference is small enough not to create those kinks yet?

Comment: They come off the manufacturing machine together, and relatively flat, then they're rolled up.  Your better toilet paper has the property of being flexible, so the effects from being curled around the roll can be "absorbed".

Comment: Not certain but unless the TP is totally rigid, the outer ply will stretch slightly depending on the degree of curvature. So towards the inside of a roll, the inner ply may bunch up though more likely the outer ply is stretched and the inner ply isn't but honestly it may even depend on the manufacturing process (how it's wound onto the roll).